# How to set first index as blank in combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox that is bound with a datasource. In this combobox I  have to add a blank field at index 0.

I have written following code for getting records.

```
 public List<TBASubType> GetSubType(int typ)
        {
            using (var tr = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    List<TBASubType> lstSubTypes = (from sbt in session.Query<TBASubType>()
                                                    where sbt.FType == typ
                                                    select sbt).ToList();


                    tr.Commit();
                    return lstSubTypes;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    CusException cex = new CusException(ex);
                    cex.Write();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

After this it bind with combobox with data binding source as below code.

```
M3.CM.BAL.CM CMobj = new M3.CM.BAL.CM(wSession.CreateSession());
                lstSubTypes = CMobj.GetSubType(type);
                this.tBASubTypeBindingSource.DataSource = lstSubTypes;
```

Comment: Include an empty string record in your binding source?

Answer (score 37):

If you just want to select nothing initially, you can use

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex=-1;
```

Comment: No I want to add a blank row in combobox.

Answer (score 17):

Thus you can't modify Items when you are are bound to DataSource, then only option to add blank row is modifying your data source. Create some empty object and add it to data source. E.g. if you have list of some `Person` entities bound to combobox:

```
var people = Builder<Person>.CreateListOfSize(10).Build().ToList();
people.Insert(0, new Person { Name = "" });
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.DataSource = people;
```

---

You can define static property `Empty` in your class:

```
public static readonly Person Empty = new Person { Name = "" };
```

And use it to insert default blank item:

```
people.Insert(0, Person.Empty);
```

This also will allow to check if selected item is default one:

```
private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Person person = (Person)comboBox.SelectedItem;
    if (person == Person.Empty)
        MessageBox.Show("Default item selected!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        cboCustomers.Items.Add(""); // Just add a blank item first

        // Then load the records from the database
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strDBConnection);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                cboCustomers.Items.Add(dr["Name"]);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating my combo boxes, I added these lines to the end of the `Load()` method:

```
private void xyz_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.xyzTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet.xyz);
    this.comboBoxXYZ.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

replace xyz with the names you've given to your controls